# Generate PDF using html string

Tags: java, html, pdf

I have an HTML file which is represented as a `String` in my source code. 
I wish to generate a PDF output containing the rendered version of the HTML.

(e.g. `<p>` in the `String` should represent a paragraph as with HTML)

How can I achieve this in my application - what libraries are available for this purpose?

Comment: Just to clarify: Do you want the rendered version of the HTML as a PDF?
In that case you will probably not find any high-level library for this in the standard JDK since you will need a web agent to render the HTML and then capture and convert the output to PDF.
Moreoever - as "displayed in the browser" is very different from browser to browser. So you take into account which browser. Check this project https://code.google.com/archive/p/flying-saucer/ it might interest you.

Comment: Try [OPEN HTML TO PDF](https://github.com/danfickle/openhtmltopdf) I have tested it a while ago and have had good results. Your HTML needs to be well-formed.

Comment: @tortal is flying-saucer and the link provided by Eritrean - both are same. which one is good to go..Yes, i need the rendered version of HTML as PDF...Basically how it looks like after parsed by the browser...

Comment: @Joseph Yes, I noticed that the one that I linked was outdated.
But do take notice that ´XHTML´ means that it should conform to W3C standard. And "OPEN_HTML_TO_PDF" claims HTML5 support. HTML5 which does not need the structure to be well-formed in the same sense that XHTML does. So keep an eye open for what they really mean by HTML5 support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the [Apache PDFBox](https://pdfbox.apache.org).
But you will still need to do the mapping from html to pdf.
For your example you will need to transform `<p>` into a paragraph in the pdf.

Comment: This would be an additional barrier..How about flying-saucer ?

Comment: @Joseph, you should try the https://github.com/danfickle/openhtmltopdf as eritrean suggested in the comments because it uses pdf box which is newer and faster then iText - the tool that flying-saucer uses. But if you really need to change or configure something, you will have to do manual transformation.

Comment: @yevgeniy.batulin You should not have posted this as an answer as it does not answer the question. It simply links to a PDF-library.

OP asked for libraries that would also render the HTML.

Comment: Reddit has /r/learnjava and /r/javahelp